# Fill form using ajax in a multipart/form-data

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, forms, servlets

I have a problem with Ajax: I want to fill the form when someone insert a book's isbn, if the book already exist.

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work

Here is the form.

```
            <form action="/Libreria_Tweb/Operation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="operation" onsubmit="return controlla()">
            <p class="submit">
            <select name="tipoInfo" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                <option value="addBook"> Inserisci libro </option>
                <option value="alterBook"> Modifica libro </option> 
            </select>
            </p>
            <div id="alter" style="text-align: left; display: none;"> <p>
            <label>Vecchio ISBN </label> <input type="text" name="oldIsbn" />
            </p></div>
            <p>
            <label>ISBN:</label> <input type="text" name="isbn" onchange="makeRequest(this.value)"/>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Titolo:</label> <input type="text" name="titolo" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Autore: </label><input type="text" name="autore" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Categoria: </label>
            <select name="categoria">
                <option value="musica">Musica</option>
                <option value="letteratura">Letteratura</option>
                <option value="cucina">Cucina</option>
                <option value="informatica">Informatica</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Prezzo:</label> <input type="text" name="prezzo" />
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Copertina:</label> <input type="file" name="copertina"  />
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="operation" value="Invia" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

Here is the method makeRequest(isbn):

```
    function makeRequest(isbn) {
      var xmlHttpReq = getXMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpReq);
      xmlHttpReq.open("POST", "/Operation?operation=getBook&isbn="+isbn, true);
      xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlHttpReq.send(null);
    }
```

And here is the Servlet for take data:

```
Object[] arr = dbm.getElemById(request);

response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.print(arr);
```

where getElemById return an array wich contains all book's data.

**PS: I can't use JQuery, Json, etcetera..., only Ajax and "simple" Java.**

(Sorry for my English)